# unable to create AI Platform Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I tried to create a notebook instance in GCP AI platform , which is not getting created . I can see the error as-

"There are no available networks. Make sure there is atleast a network within this region".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to create the AI notebook instance in a region that does not contain any subnetwork, it will throw this error:

> There are no available networks. Make sure there is at least a network
> within this region

In order to resolve your issue, try one of the following:

1. For creating a Notebook instance in the same region, you need to create a subnet in that region for the VPC network you are using. To create a new subnet you can follow [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#add-subnets).
2. Or else you can create a Notebook instance in some other region where the subnet is available. To create a notebook instance you can follow [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/create-new).